# anchor links on android not working when using overflow auto

Tags: android, browser, overflow, anchor, hyperlink

I have an extremely simple page with one anchor link:

http://iklimt.com/test/public/life/index2.html

It works as it should on every browser except on the Android browser. If I remove the `overflow:auto` setting from the main `<div>` then it works, but I don't want that. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: auto` and `overflow:scroll` are not supported by the android browser as stated here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2911 the solution you've got is to insert some custom scroll lib in javascript if you want to achieve the same effect everywhere... suggested [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html)

Comment: But that seems to be a very old article from 2009. Also, anchor link aside, the overflow: auto works fine, is just that the anchors don't work.